# Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'SignData'

Tags: powershell, jwt, rsa

I am trying to generate A JWT token with the help of Private key using powershell but getting the above mentioned error. Would really appreciate if anyone can help me into that . i am posting my code snippet here below :

```
$now = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$createDate = [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date($now) -UFormat "%s"))
$expiryDate = [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date($now.AddHours(1)) -UFormat "%s"))

$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\Users\agarni\Desktop\NetsuitSentinelIntegration.pfx","Password@12345")

$jwtheader = [Ordered]@{
alg = "RS256"
typ = "JWT"
kid = "1l68owapqcbNnMf0lc3Q0-KFqRgZi4RwA" } | ConvertTo-Json


$Jwtpayload = [ordered]@{
iss="f01b3163ec8dfd402f32d0ba14fa97da9776b817f1cc7cf08bd952"
scope="Restlets"
iat="$starttime"
exp="$Expirytime"
aud="https://api.netsuit.com/services/rest/auth/oauth2/v2/token"
} | Convertto-JSON


$rsa = get-content C:\privatekey.key -Raw

ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $payloadJson -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null } # Validating that the parameter is actually JSON - if not, generate breaking error
    catch { throw "The supplied JWT payload is not JSON: $payloadJson" }
    #>

$encodedHeader = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($jwtHeader)) -replace '\+','-' -replace '/','_' -replace '='
$encodedPayload = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Jwtpayload)) -replace '\+','-' -replace '/','_' -replace '='

    $jwt = $encodedHeader + '.' + $encodedPayload # The first part of the JWT

    $toSign = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($jwt)
    
   
        # Overloads tested with RSACryptoServiceProvider, RSACng, RSAOpenSsl
        try { $sig = [Convert]::ToBase64String($rsa.SignData($toSign,[Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256,[Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding]::Pkcs1)) -replace '\+','-' -replace '/','_' -replace '='

    $jwt = $jwt + '.' + $sig

    return $jwt
```

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Signdata'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $rsa.Signdata($tosign,[Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName])
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: `$rsa` in your code is the result of reading the content from a file, looking at the method you're trying to use (`SignData`) it seems you're missing the part where you define a new `RSACryptoServiceProvider`